# ffmpeg: for a single audio file, how do I raise volume for quieter parts and reduce volume for louder parts?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have tried to read the documentations of ffmpeg loudnorm, but I am not sure whether it means finding a maximum loudness and uniformly raise/lower the volume of the whole audio (which isn't what I want), or it means raising volume for quieter parts and reducing volume for louder parts (which is what I want).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#dynaudnorm

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a compander. For `ffmpeg` this is available as a filter. It works quite well, but it has a difficult syntax, and it might require some tweaking.

As an example, you can use:

```
 ffplay some_music.mp3 -af 'compand=.3|.3:1|1:-90/-60|-60/-40|-40/-30|-20/-20:6:0:-90:0.2'
```

(I used `ffplay` here, but the syntax for `ffmpeg` is the same)

Comment: dynaudnorm will do this without needing a manual curves specification.